# A particular sequence of trigonometric polynomials.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

A trigonometric polynomial be a function defined as
$$a_0 + \sum_{k=0}^n \left[a_k \cos(kt) + b_k \sin(kt)\right].\tag1$$

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we define $$q_n(t)=\left( \frac{1+\cos t}{2}\right)^n.$$ Using the fact that $$\cos(kt)\cos(t)=\frac{1}{2}\left[\cos((k+1)t)+\cos((k-1)t) \right],\tag2$$
how is it possible to prove that the $q_n$ are of the form $(1)$? Could you give me some suggestions?

$\Large \text{My attempt}$

We observe that $$q_n(t)=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} \cos^k(t).$$

At this point the powers of the cosine can be calculated recursively with formula $(2)$ as follows:

$$\cos^2(t)=\frac{\cos(2t)}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\cos^3(t)=\cos^2(t)\cos t=\frac{\cos(3t)}{4}+\frac{3\cos t}{4}$$

> **Question** Is this enough to conclude?

Comment: Why not expand  the bracket and then use the power reduction formula for trig functions?

Comment: Simple induction argument.

Comment: Try $\frac{1+\cos t}{2}=\cos^2\frac{t}{2}$ maybe?